# Ссылка для добавления отзывов

Tags: yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

Есть ли у яндекса возможность создания прямой ссылки на диалог/форму добавления отзыва?

[image]

Например, вот так это у google: https://support.google.com/business/answer/7035772?hl=ru

Answer (score 1):

Ссылка выглядит так https://yandex.ru/maps/213/moscow/?orgpage%5Bid%5D=1094008369&add-review=true&mode=orgpage . Не нашёл, чтобы это где-то было описано, но наверно это будет продолжать работать.

Comment: Работает, но только на декстопе, нет варианта для мобильной версии?

Comment: это лучше в техподдержке яндекса спросить