# Ссылка на добавление отзыва об организации для мобильного

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Есть ли вариант сделать такую ссылку, чтобы при переходе по ней с мобильного телефона, человеку открывалось окно добавления отзыва о конкретной организации?

Был похожий вопрос - [Ссылка для добавления отзывов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/882915/%D0%A1%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2)

Там предложили вариант решения вот такой ссылкой - https://yandex.ru/maps/213/moscow/?orgpage%5Bid%5D=1094008369&add-review=true&mode=orgpage , но она действует только для декстопов, на мобильнике при открытии появляется голая карта без окошка отзыва.

В крайнем случае меня бы устроил вариант url карт или справочника, на котором бы показывалась организация и была кнопка "оставить отзыв", но такой ссылки я не нашел.
Например на странице организации на картах (когда слева инфа об организации, а справа карта с меткой) на декстопе есть форма - "Вы посещали это место? Да/Нет", с которой можно оставить отзыв, а вот эта же страница с мобильной версии такой формы не имеет.

То же самое со страницей организации в справочнике типа yandex.ru/maps/org/название_организации/ (которая без карты). Там на декстопе есть кнопка "Оставить отзыв", а на мобильной версии ее нету.

Единственное как можно оставить отзыв с мобильника на картах - это если сам забиваешь название организации в поиске, там вверху появляется инфа из справочника, в этой инфе есть вкладка с отзывами при переходе на которую появляется "Оцените пожалуйста это место" и пять звезд. Но конкретного юрл эта вкладка не имеет, это все юрл страницы результатов поиска.

Comment: https://yandex.ru/maps/org/kfc/145023758804 вот, например, ссылка полученная через форму "поделиться" с мобильной карты. На странице организации есть внизу форма для оценки и отзыва. Это не то что нужно?

Comment: Я не вижу в мобильной версии чтобы была форма для оценки. На декстопе, да, есть "Вы посещали это место", а на мобильной версии такого, или какой либо другой формы нету.

Comment: Если установлены яндекс карты приложение, то по ссылке автоматически открывается приложение. И там, да, есть возможность оставить отзыв. А если открывать в браузере, то отзыв оставить нельзя.

Comment: К сожалению, в настоящий момент такой возможности и правда нет.